# how to add the headers to csv file only one in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I tried many ways/combinations to insert headers (I need to add two column headers) but the file doesn't accept headers at file creation. At best, I get headers as rows come into the file one after the other. I can't see how to enter the headers only once persistently. Can you see in the code below where I could make some change please? Thanks.

```
            with open(MYFILE, "w", newline='') as csvWriter, open('read.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvReader:
            if keyword != "q":
                fieldnames = [engine, keyword]
                #fieldnames = ['Engine', 'Keywords']
                # writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter, fieldnames=[engine, keyword], extrasaction='ignore')
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()

                reader = csv.DictReader(csvReader, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writerow({"Engine": engine, "Keywords": keyword})
                writer.writerows(reader)
```

I'm trying to save data into a csv file. I have two columns but no headers currently. I'd need some column titles like in any spreadsheet basically.

UPDATE ==============================================
I've tried to insert to no avail the first block hereafter before and after the 2nd one. There is certainly something I'm not doing right but I don't know. Any suggestion, please?

```
STATUS = "quit"
print("Press [q] to quit at any time")
menu_engine = {}
menu_engine['1'] = "Google Search - Large Results"
menu_engine['2'] = "Google Search - Small Results"
menu_engine['3'] = "Yahoo Search - Large Results"
menu_engine['4'] = "Yahoo Search - Small Results"

while True:
options = menu_engine.keys()
for entry in options:
    print(entry, menu_engine[entry])
engine = input("Enter your Type of Search: ")

while STATUS != "q":
    keyword = input("Enter keyword(s): ")

    with open(MYFILE, "a", newline='') as csvWriter:
        if keyword != "q":
            fieldnames = [engine, keyword]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
            writer.writeheader()
```

THE EXPECTED OUTPUT in the CSV File:

```
    Engine Number,Keywords
    4,man man
    4,mate mate
```

Comment: what are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: @Chris Doyle. I edited my post. See at the bottom of it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample of the file content and sample expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you write the header with `writeheader()` then you can just write the rows

```py
import csv
with open('new.dat', "w", newline='') as csvWriter, open('test.dat', 'r', newline='') as csvReader:
        fieldnames = ['Engine', 'Keywords']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvReader, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

**INPUT FILE**

```
sef,56
sfd,67
eryt,67
sdfsf,34
```

**OUTPUT FILE**

```
Engine,Keywords
sef,56
sfd,67
eryt,67
sdfsf,34
```

**UPDATE**

I felt there should be an easier way to do this and seems you can use `fileinput` module from the standard python library to edit the same file inplace and insert the record at the start. this will save you having to the move or rename files.

```py
import fileinput
headers = ['Engine','Type']
with fileinput.input('test.dat', inplace=1) as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if my_file.isfirstline():
            print(",".join(headers))
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: I'm on it. Cheers. I need to make sure I copy 'new.dat' to the 'test.dat' name. I'll use test.csv as I'm on Linux.

Comment: i feel there must be an easier way than this though as this seems a lot or work just to add a line at the start

Comment: updated the answer with a way to edit the file inplace and add in the line at the start

Comment: Is the test.dat extension supposed to do something that Linux cannot do or can it just be replaced with a test.csv file?

Comment: The extention makes no difference. I just call my test file test.dat as I use the same file to test lots of different data. So feel free to use .csv extention

Comment: Your update works. I just placed it after the last block in my update. I'm on the duplication issue now. Thanks Chris. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["new_column"]=" "
df.to_csv("your_file.csv", index= False)
print(df)      #to see if it's what you need
```